# solr search for documents where a field doesn't exist

Tags: lucene, solr, lucene.net, solrnet

How do I search for those document in a SOLR index which do not contain a specified field?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`-field:[* TO *]`

In SolrNet, use a negated [SolrHasValueQuery](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md)

Comment: That's insanely expensive.  There has to be a better way, but I haven't looked yet.  At minimum, you should create an empty field marker (e.g. NULL) and index that.

Comment: @KyleMaxwell of course, doing it at index-time is better... if not, I don't think there's a better way to do it at query-time.

Comment: Note this only works for fields that are indexed.  Doing this for non-indexed fields will returns all records.

Comment: I've tested this request directly on a fairly large index and it is not that expensive (with solr 4.10 and on a docvalues field)

Comment: we can use -field:* also