# Solr Query - return all results that do not contain a certain field

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any way to write a query that will return all results that do not contain a certain field?

For example, let's say that I have an index of people that contains firstName, lastName and birthDate. I want to query for all people who do not have a birthDate. NOT all people where birthDate is null, but all people where there simply is no birthDate field. Is this possible?

EDIT: MATAN pointed me to the answer here - [solr search for documents where a field doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365369/solr-search-for-documents-where-a-field-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365369/solr-search-for-documents-where-a-field-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative at field. like that:

```
-birthDate:*
or
-birthDate:[* TO *]
```